# Working with PowerShell functions passing and getting values

Tags: powershell

A PowerShell script works from the command line.

When attempting to pass the parameter in the script then no values are appearing when the function is called to pass the values the rest of the program I tried using scope and parameters inside the function.

Comment: Can you update your question with some example of code you tried? It's hard to say what you are doing wrong without.

Answer (score 5):

A sample from your script would highly help in giving you an accurate answer. That said, here is a generic answer that shows a script with functions and without functions in PowerShell.

```
Function Sum {
    Param ([int]$a,[int]$b)

    return $a+$b
}
```

So, when you have this in a script, you dot source the script. So, you can call the function directly from cmdline. For example

`Sum 4 5` will return 9.

Now, without functions, let  us say sum.ps1 has the following code:

```
Param ([int]$a,[int]$b)
$a+$b
```

You can call, `.\sum.ps1 4 5` at the console or whereever, and it returns 9 again.

It is not necessary to use `param()` at all. You can use $args array to retrieve the parameters. But, it makes sense to bind parameters to a type and give them a name using `Param()`

Answer (score 1):

Is it that you want to call a specific function in the script? You can do this by .sourcing and then invoking. Here we call the function sign-script defined in utils.ps1, passing the argument somescript.ps1 to the function.

```
. .\utils.ps1;sign-script somescript.ps1
```

Note the extra dot at the start of the line